# Less - parametric mixin with shorthand numeric and or string values, with rem and px fallback

Tags: css, less, mixins

Using Less, I'm trying output css combination shorthand values for properties, whilst detecting the type of a value passed as a variable depending on how many values are passed as variables.

- one value `@v1`
- two values `@v1` and `@v2`
- four values `@v1`, `@v2`, `@v3` and `@v4`

And for each variable detected, check if is is a number greater than 0, and if so output a rem and px value for each property value, so the complied css might be something like:

```
.demobox{
  border-width: 10px 20px 0 0;
  border-width: 1rem 2rem 0 0;
  padding: 0 50px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

This is fairly easy to solve where no more than two values are ever declared, but If I need four values, the number of nested mixins and guards becomes pretty complicated.

***The reason for opting for rems is the ease of implementation compared to ems, and prevents having the headache of remembering to have to reset the font-size to every parent item. Additionally the older device support issues are comparable, for both rems and ems, so I figure a px fallback works best.***

Here's' the [code pen](http://codepen.io/onebitrocket/pen/hwqCi) of where I am so far, but I'll try and explain my workings so far as best as I can.

Is there a way to simplify this process? I'm new to less. I imagine there is a much simpler way to detect

- the number of declared values
- the type of each value
- if the number value requires a rem and px value fallback

Thanks

I have a parametric mixin which outputs a `rem` value and `px` fallback value along with the declared property

```
@root-font-size: 10;

.rem(@property, @v1) when (@v1 = @v1){
    @px1: @v1 * @root-font-size;
    @{property}:  ~'@{px1}px';
    @{property}: ~'@{v1}rem';
}
```

This is great for quickly generating both the rem and pixel fallback for a set css property

```
/* call the rem mixin */
.demobox {
    .rem(margin, 2);
}
/* output */
.demobox {
    margin: 20px;
    margin: 2rem;
}
```

One really useful case for this is generating `font-size` and `line-height` values with fallbacks

```
/* call the font-classes mixin */
.font-classes(@fontsize, @lineheight) {
    .rem(font-size, @fontsize);
    .rem(line-height, @lineheight);
}
/* output */
.demobox {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 24px;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
}
```

So far so good, i can output a rem and pixel fallback for a single value and nest the `.rem` mixin with in another mixin.

At the moment, if I want to pass more than one value I have to call the `.rem` mixin for each required value:

```
/* call the rem mixin */
.demobox {
    .rem(margin-left, 2);
    .rem(margin-right, 2);
}
/* output */
.demobox {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do is pass either one two or four values with a property to the`.rem` mixin.

```
.demobox {
    .rem(margin, 2, 1);
}
```

As I mentioned earier this is not so difficult for two values, and to check what the value type is. This requires a version of the `.rem` mixin with a gaurd applied to check that `@v2` is declared.

This the triggers a nested `.rem-two` mixin.

```
// when there are two values
.rem(@property, @v1, @v2) when (@v1 = @v1) and (@v2 = @v2){
    .rem-two(@property, @v1, @v2);
}
```

There are three versions of the `.rem-two`, where the guards are different for each.

Detect if both `@v1` and `@v2` are numbers greater than 0

```
.rem-two(@property, @v1, @v2) when (@v1 = @v1) and not (@v1 = 0) and (isnumber(@v1)) and (@v2 = @v2) and not (@v2 = 0) and (isnumber(@v2)) {
    @px1: @v1 * @root-font-size;
    @px2: @v2 * @root-font-size;
    @{property}:  ~'@{px1}px @{px2}px';
    @{property}: ~'@{v1}rem @{v2}rem';
}
```

Detect if both `@v1` and `@v2` are numbers greater than 0

```
.rem-two(@property, @v1, @v2) when (@v1 = @v1) and not (@v1 = 0) and (isnumber(@v1)) and (@v2 = 0), not (isnumber(@v2)){
    @px1: @v1 * @root-font-size;
    @{property}:  ~'@{px1}px @{v2}';
    @{property}: ~'@{v2}rem @{v2}';
}

/* call the rem mixin */
.demobox {
    .rem(margin, 2, 1);
}
/* outputs */
.demobox {
    margin: 10px 20px;
    margin: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

Detect if both `@v1` is a number greater than 0 and `@v2` is either a value of 0 or not a number

*the '@px2' pixel fallback is not required, so is removed.*

```
.rem-two(@property, @v1, @v2) when (@v1 = @v1) and not (@v1 = 0) and (isnumber(@v1)) and (@v2 = 0), not (isnumber(@v2)){
    @px1: @v1 * @root-font-size;
    @{property}:  ~'@{px1}px @{v2}';
    @{property}: ~'@{v2}rem @{v2}';
}
/* call the rem mixin */
.demobox {
    .rem(margin, 2, auto);
}
/* outputs */
.demobox {
    margin: 10px auto;
    margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

Detect if both `@v1` is either a value of 0 or not a number and `@v2` is a number greater than 0

*the '@px1' pixel fallback is not required, so is removed.*

```
.rem-two(@property, @v1, @v2) when (@v1 = 0), not (isnumber(@v1)) and (@v2 = @v2) and not (@v2 = 0) and (isnumber(@v2)){
    @px2: @v2 * @root-font-size;
    @{property}:  ~'@{v1} @{px2}px';
    @{property}: ~'@{v1} @{v2}rem';
}
/* call the rem mixin */
.demobox {
    .rem(margin, 0, 20);
}
/* outputs */
.demobox {
    margin: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 2rem;
}
```

As there are only 3 possibilities for this two value version of the mixin  It is easy to solve this problem, but with 3 or four values the number of nested mixins and guards expands to cover all possibilities.

As additional examples. 
I have repurposed the `.rem` mixin to output `px` and `rem`, `border-radius` values with vendor prefixing, to ensure that it only processes numeric values, I have guards to check if the value being passed is a number that is greater that 0

```
.prefix(@property, @v1) when (isnumber(@v1)) and (@v1 > 0) {
    @px1: @v1 * @root-font-size;
    -webkit-@{property}: ~'@{px1}px';
    -moz-@{property}: ~'@{px1}px';
    @{property}: ~'@{px1}px';
    -webkit-@{property}: ~'@{v1}rem';
    -moz-@{property}: ~'@{v1}rem';
    @{property}: ~'@{v1}rem';
}
/* call prefix mixin */
.demobox{
    .prefix(border-radius,5);
}
/* output */
.demobox{
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5rem;
    -moz-border-radius: 5rem;
}
```

I can swap the guards around to check that the value is either 0 (so i can reset a property) or if it is anything else than a number, such as outputting prefixed box sizing.

The reason I ask a guard of `not (isnumber(@v1))`, rather than `(isstring(@v1))`, is so I don't have to add single quotes the the value `'border-box'.

```
.prefix(@property, @v1) when (@v1 = 0), not (isnumber(@v1)) {
    -webkit-@{property}: ~'@{v1}';
    -moz-@{property}: ~'@{v1}';
    @{property}: ~'@{v1}';
}
/* call prefix mixin */
.demobox {
    .prefix(box-sizing, border-box);
}
/* output */
.demobox {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Well, personally I see the main problem with all this is that you're trying to make it "too smart". I.e. trying to cover all possible uses and bothering with quite questionable pre-emptive optimization. Normally it's never worth it (too complex to implement and it *will* still fail to "cover everything" eventually). For example speaking of suppressing `margin: 0` or `margin: 0 0` etc: those are valid CSS values *meaning* zero margin and not `"no margin value"` so to not output `margin: 0` just do not call `.rem(margin, 0)` instead of harcoding this case into the `.rem()` itself.

Comment: And, as always, for vendor prefixes use a dedicated tool (e.g. [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer), [-prefix-free](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree)). Same goes for final CSS optimization (e.g. `margin: 0px` -> `margin: 0` -> [clean-css](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css) et al.).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things if you treat passed arguments as an array (a simplified impl., there're too many requirements in your snippet to cover in an *example*), **Less 1.7.x** or higher:

```
// usage

@root-font-size: 10;

div {
    .rem(border-radius, 1, margin, 2 auto, padding, 4 5 6 inherit);
}

// impl:

.rem-value_(@p, @v, @u) when (isnumber(@v)) {
    @{p}+_: (@v * @u);
}

.rem-value_(@p, @v, @u) when (default()) {
    @{p}+_: @v;
}

.rem(@args...) {
    .i; .i(@i: length(@args)) when (@i > 0) {
        .i((@i - 2));
        @property: extract(@args, (@i - 1));
        @values:   extract(@args,  @i);
        .j(@property, @values, (1px * @root-font-size));
        .j(~'@{property} ', @values, 1rem); // have to use ~'@{property} ' hack to isolate rem and px properties;
    }
    .j(@p, @v, @u, @j: length(@v)) when (@j > 0) {
        .j(@p, @v, @u, (@j - 1));
        .rem-value_(@p, extract(@v, @j), @u);
    }
}
```

The loop is quite scary but the value output mixin is pretty transparent and fully customizable (you can add more conditions if you need to).