# How to convert margin: 0 auto to .rem(margin:..)?

Tags: css, less

This is a sample code how we use rem in our website:

```
.width(1200px);
.rem(padding, 100px);
.rem2(padding, 100px, 50px);
.rem3(padding, 100px, 50px, 0);
```

So basically, .rem() automatically converts px units to rem so that it will adjust to the dimension of the root (html) element.

However, what if I want to convert `margin: 0 auto;` to `.rem()`. How will I do the auto margin using this function?

Comment: Well, your `.rem` is not a *function*, it does not actually *return* any values you can assign to a property (if you look at it closely you'll see that your `.rem` already has a property and you can't really assign a property to another property, can you?).  There're several solutions to the problem: 1. Real [`functions`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-list-of-less-plugins). 2. Simple mixin working with single value only 3. More miixin trickery for properties with multiple values ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083818)).

Comment: [Example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn.rem(%40property%2C%20%40value)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40your-px-to-rem-constant%3A%20.33rem%3B%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40your-px-to-rem-constant%20*%20%40value%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20usage%5Cn%5Cndiv%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.rem(margin%2C%2011px)%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D) for 2 (though it won't fit your example example anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

`auto` is (in very simple terms) *whatever is left over*.

That varies depending on the size of the browser window.

There's no way to calcaulte it at the time LESS runs.